# Modify bin firmware file of an old phone

Tags: binary-analysis, firmware, firmware-analysis, binwalk, binary-editing

I am trying to remove/disable some system apps ( Messages, Games, Radio or Calendar ) and remove/replace the boot screen from **samsung E1200y**.

So i start searching for the way to do that...

I used HxH hex editor for trying to modify the firmware bin file.

i searched for the strings -> deleted some strings that have the keyword Messages, Games, Radio or Calendar -> but that doesn't looks correct

So i searched more and found **binwalk** in linux.

I used it and here's the results

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
197170        0x30232         Unix path: /source/base/src/doidleonpage.c
290966        0x47096         Unix path: /source/efs/src/efs_item.c
340308        0x53154         Unix path: /Layer1/source/c/datacnfproc.c
439316        0x6B414         Unix path: /Layer1/source/c/systeminfo.c
454360        0x6EED8         Unix path: /chip_module/busmonitor/v5/busmonitor_phy_v5.c
1044005       0xFEE25         MySQL MISAM index file Version 7
1047421       0xFFB7D         MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 5
1076680       0x106DC8        MySQL MISAM index file Version 3
1083384       0x1087F8        MySQL ISAM index file Version 2
1084942       0x108E0E        MySQL MISAM index file Version 2
1095977       0x10B929        MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 11
1115351       0x1104D7        MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 2
1133241       0x114AB9        MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 5
1163534       0x11C10E        MySQL MISAM compressed data file Version 9
1169361       0x11D7D1        MySQL MISAM index file Version 2
1169878       0x11D9D6        MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 1
1172147       0x11E2B3        MySQL MISAM index file Version 7
1175240       0x11EEC8        MySQL MISAM index file Version 5
1216892       0x12917C        Unix path: /source/src/c/sci_mem.c
1222192       0x12A630        Unix path: /source/src/c/threadx_os.c
1235544       0x12DA58        Unix path: /source/src/c/sci_log.c
1240224       0x12ECA0        Unix path: /source/src/c/threadx_appmem.c
3853392       0x3ACC50        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 16777216
                              bytes, uncompressed size: 4096 bytes
3858764       0x3AE14C        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 16777216
                              bytes, uncompressed size: 4096 bytes
3858804       0x3AE174        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 16777216
                              bytes, uncompressed size: 4096 bytes
3858844       0x3AE19C        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 16777216
                              bytes, uncompressed size: 4096 bytes
3984072       0x3CCAC8        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5A, dictionary size: 16777216
                              bytes, uncompressed size: 4096 bytes
4268656       0x412270        PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format,, 60 x 80 x 4
6060579       0x5C7A23        XML document, version: "1.0"
6064503       0x5C8977        XML document, version: "1.0"
6067639       0x5C95B7        XML document, version: "1.0"
6069663       0x5C9D9F        XML document, version: "1.0"
6071627       0x5CA54B        XML document, version: "1.0"
6073771       0x5CADAB        XML document, version: "1.0"
6075911       0x5CB607        XML document, version: "1.0"
6078019       0x5CBE43        XML document, version: "1.0"
6082035       0x5CCDF3        XML document, version: "1.0"
6084719       0x5CD86F        XML document, version: "1.0"
6087079       0x5CE1A7        XML document, version: "1.0"
6088615       0x5CE7A7        XML document, version: "1.0"
6091495       0x5CF2E7        XML document, version: "1.0"
6094375       0x5CFE27        XML document, version: "1.0"
6098727       0x5D0F27        XML document, version: "1.0"
6101915       0x5D1B9B        XML document, version: "1.0"
6105723       0x5D2A7B        XML document, version: "1.0"
6108279       0x5D3477        XML document, version: "1.0"
6110791       0x5D3E47        XML document, version: "1.0"
6113675       0x5D498B        Unix path: /Customer/XFV/PowerOffAnim/shutdown-01.bmp" width="128"
                              height="128">
6115267       0x5D4FC3        XML document, version: "1.0"
6118599       0x5D5CC7        XML document, version: "1.0"
6121467       0x5D67FB        XML document, version: "1.0"
```

after extracting the .bin file, i got

```
total 71480
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir    4096 Oct 30 01:33 3ACC50
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 4535216 Oct 30 01:33 3ACC50.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir    4096 Oct 30 01:33 3AE14C
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 4529844 Oct 30 01:33 3AE14C.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir    4096 Oct 30 01:33 3AE174
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 4529804 Oct 30 01:33 3AE174.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir    4096 Oct 30 01:33 3AE19C
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 4529764 Oct 30 01:33 3AE19C.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir    4426 Oct 30 01:33 3CCAC8
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 4404536 Oct 30 01:33 3CCAC8.7z
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2328029 Oct 30 01:33 5C7A23.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2324105 Oct 30 01:33 5C8977.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2320969 Oct 30 01:33 5C95B7.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2318945 Oct 30 01:33 5C9D9F.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2316981 Oct 30 01:33 5CA54B.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2314837 Oct 30 01:33 5CADAB.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2312697 Oct 30 01:33 5CB607.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2310589 Oct 30 01:33 5CBE43.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2306573 Oct 30 01:33 5CCDF3.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2303889 Oct 30 01:33 5CD86F.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2301529 Oct 30 01:33 5CE1A7.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2299993 Oct 30 01:33 5CE7A7.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2297113 Oct 30 01:33 5CF2E7.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2294233 Oct 30 01:33 5CFE27.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2289881 Oct 30 01:33 5D0F27.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2286693 Oct 30 01:33 5D1B9B.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2282885 Oct 30 01:33 5D2A7B.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2280329 Oct 30 01:33 5D3477.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2277817 Oct 30 01:33 5D3E47.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2273341 Oct 30 01:33 5D4FC3.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2270009 Oct 30 01:33 5D5CC7.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 shakir shakir 2267141 Oct 30 01:33 5D67FB.xml
```

My questions:

1. How to get the .c files like /source/base/src/doidleonpage.c ?
2. Why the file's name begin with hex ?
3. What to do next in order to get all the files ?
4. What's the correct way to pack the files to a .bin file after unpacking and
   modifying them to flash it to the phone ?
5. Am i in the correct path ?

Firmware Link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/yl056lfk8xubt1o/GT-E1200Y_Hebrew_SINGAL_SIM.bin/file

Comment: I think [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17437/36140) on a similar question might help you.